# Script terminates prematurely after do loop. Last "echo" is not executed.

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, do-while, do-loops

I am looking to execute the following script below. The issue I am encountering is it will not execute anything after the do loop. It doesn't matter what I happen to have after the loop, it never executes, so I am def missing something somewhere.

Also, any suggestions on a more efficient way or writing this script? I am very new to the scripting environment and very open to better ways of going about things.

```
#!/bin/bash

# mcidas environment

PATH=$HOME/bin:
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sww/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/mcidas/bin
PATH=$PATH:/home/mcidas/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/ucb
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/X11:/common/tool/bin:.

export PATH

MCPATH=$HOME/mcidas/data
MCPATH=$MCPATH:/home/mcidas/data

export MCPATH

#variables
basedir1="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MOD02QKM" #TERRA
basedir2="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MYD02QKM" #AQUA
day=`date +%j`
day1=`date +"%j" -d "-1 day"`
hour=`date -u +"%H"`
min=`date -u +"%m"`
year=`date -u +"%Y"`
segment=1
count=$(ls /satellite/modis_processed/ | grep -v ^d | wc -l) 
count_max=25
files=(/satellite/modis_processed/*)



if [ $hour -ge "17" ]; then

workinghour="16"
echo "Searching for hour $workinghour"
url="${basedir2}/${year}/${day1}/MYD02QKM.A${year}${day1}.${workinghour}*.006.${year}*" 
wget -r -nd --no-parent -nc -e robots=off  -R 'index.*' -P /satellitemodis/ $url 
#find /satellite/modis/ -type f -mmin -30 -exec cp "{}" /satellite/modis_processed/ \;

for files in /satellite/modis_processed/*
do

    echo "The number used for the data file is ${count}"
    echo "The number used for the image file is ${segment}"

    export segment
    export count

    #Run McIDAS
mcenv <<- 'EOF'
imgcopy.k MODISD.${count} MODISI.${segment} BAND=1 SIZE=SAME
imgremap.k MODISD.${segment} MODISI.${segment} BAND=1 SIZE=ALL PRO=MERC 
imgcha.k MODISI.${segment} CTYPE=BRIT
exit
EOF

    segment=`expr ${segment} + 1`
    count=`expr ${count} - 1`

    #Reset Counter if equal or greater than 25
    if [[ $segment -ge $count_max ]]; then
    segment=1
    fi

    find /satellite/awips -type f -name "AREA62*" -exec mv "{}" /awips2/edex/data/manual/ \; 
done;

echo "We have exported ${segment} converted modis files to EDEX."
fi
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? You seem to have one `fi` too many.

Comment: I recall that, it's bash (marked as `/bin/sh`, a should-be shooting offence ...). But I still see nothing that makes the loop terminate, since `files` is never modified.

Comment: @that-other-guy I made a mistake when adding it to stackoverflow. I removed one of the closing `fi`. I am not receiving any errors. I wasn't sure if I had nested the `if` statement wrong or what, but I am not getting anything syntactically wrong on my end.

Comment: @dhke the shebang should be bash instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- including the "minimal" part: Code examples should be trimmed down to the smallest possible thing that can demonstrate the same problem. (Likewise, "verifiable": Code samples should be made to operate in environments other than the OP's, so anyone with a proposed solution can test whether that solution actually does fix the problem in practice).

Comment: @WxJack Yeah, the script uses arrays and at least another bashism (test -f on array). But the main problem seems to be that I see nothing that makes `while [ -f "$files" ]`  terminate, which happens more or less only when `/satellite/modis_processed/` is cleaned out.

Comment: @WxJack, yes, the shebang absolutely should be bash -- you're using arrays in here, and the POSIX sh standard doesn't provide them.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you very much -- I will change it up and I will def use that site in the future. @dhke would it be better to change it to `for files in /satellite/modis_processed/*` or would that not make any difference?

Comment: I changed to bash, but I am still running into the same issue... the final line of the script is not displaying. ShellCheck is not popping up with any significant errors.

Comment: This [mcve] is working for me. Maybe in your original script something larger is causing it. Can you test it by replacing `mcenv <<-EOF` with `cat<<-EOF`? If the test passes and prints the last line then the issue is with mcidas.

Comment: @alvits I commented the EOF stuff out totally and it still does not execute the last echo. I think it is something with the loop itself.

Comment: Well, the [mcve] is working. Must be something with your original code that we cannot guess.

Comment: I actually rewrote the script from scratch. It was driving me crazy trying to figure this out. It appears to be working correctly now. I appreciate everyone's time on this. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a here-document in that script.  That here-document is not properly terminated. The end marker, `EOF`, needs to be in the first column, not indented at all.

If you indent it, it has to be with tabs, and the start of the here-document should be `<<-'EOF'`.

The effect of the wrongly indented `EOF` marker is that the rest of the script is read as the contents of the here-document.

As Charles Duffy points out, [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend.

Comment: It was only indented like that on stackoverflow. It was properly indented in my script. I have added the dash you mentioned, but there is no change in the output. I am still not seeing echo "We have exported ${segment} converted modis files to EDEX." when the script is run.

Comment: @WxJack Well, what can I say.

Comment: I rewrote the script from scratch and it appears to be working now. Seems like it was just a quirk in my coding somewhere. I appreciate your help regardless though. Thank you. :)